# 3 party pivot connection with Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, eloquent

We have custom fields which can be created thru mysql, these fields are "owned" by a module (for example: Opportunities-module wants a "potental sales"-field and User-section wants a gender-field (with 3 select options) .

With Laravel 6 Eloquent, I am trying to fetch:

1. All opportunities
2. and custom_fields where category = 'opportunity'
3. and related custom_fields_values thru the pivot.

and then add them to the "related" array in the collection. So I can easily do:

```
$opportunity->custom_field[x]->custom_field->name
$opportunity->custom_field[x]->custom_field_value[x]->value
```

**DB:**

```
custom_fields: 
id, name, category (opportunity, client...), type (text, number, select, radio)

custom_field_custom_field_value (pivot):
custom_field_id, custom_field_value_id, parent_id (=id of the "parent" opportunity or client...), selected

custom_field_values:
id, value
```

I would love to get myself started but I am 100% stuck - do not even know where to get started with the belongstomanys etc... or if it is at all doable...

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomField extends Model
{
    public function values()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(CustomFieldValue::class);
    }
}
```

That will do it.

Usage:

```
$custom_fields = CustomField::where('category', 'opportunity')->with('values')->get();

foreach ($custom_fields as $field) : 
   $field->values; 
....
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will fetch all values for all opportunities. I want to only fetch the assiged values for that opportunity (opportunity_id is defined by pivot)

Also, it is going to fetch rought 1000 opportunites at the same time - so would prefer not to have to "foreach" on every opportunity..